# Как запретить TextView оставление пустого места справа

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте!

Добавляю в TextView текст. Если очередное слово не помещается в конце строки, оно переносится не новую строку с оставлением пустого места в конце этой строки.

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Вам нужно запретить перенос строк? Или нужно переносить слова по буквам?

Comment: мне нужно чтоб он не переводил слово оставив конец поля пустым а переводил с  - или буквами

Comment: Слово большое хочу разделив перенести как это реальзовать

Comment: В желаемое место переноса можете вставить `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

Это нормальное поведение, и исправлять его ненужно, т. к. это не является ошибкой.
Происходит так потому, что система не знает правил переноса. Вы можете задать свои собственные правила, вставив на местах возможного переноса специальный символ, который называется `zero-width space` - пробел с нулевой длинной. Он имеет код `\u200a`(или `\u200b`, не смог точно вспомнить, попробуйте оба). Использовать примерно так:

```
"тут\u200bне\u200bбудет\u200bвидно\u200bпробелов\u200bно\u200bслова\u200bбудут\u200bпереноситься"
```